# AlertDialog's in-built ListView set the default padding

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I used the Builder's setAdapter() to create an AlertDialog with a ListView. The problem is that the title and the ListView do not align. I know I can get the default padding size by setting `?dialogPreferredPadding`, but since I did not make the ListView manually, I do not have a reference to the ListView.

How can I set the ListView's padding so that the content (ListView) and the title will align?

[image]

```
    val dd = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.myitem);
    dd.add("Internet");
    dd.add("Scratch");
    dd.add("Maude");

    val ad = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .setTitle("Eh?")
            .setAdapter(dd, null)
            .create()
            .show();
```

Comment: post screenshot

Comment: "...since I did not make the ListView manually, I do not have a reference to the ListView." - If you're setting the `Adapter`, you have control over the layout used for the items, though. Set your padding there.

Comment: So, I cannot set a padding once to the ListView, but have to set a padding for each item? I thought of this, but it seemed less efficient than setting a padding to the ListView. But if that is the only way, I will do so.

Comment: first of all use `AppCompatDialog` instead of `AlertDialog` and then give a custom layout to your dialog, u can use `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_view_dialog);`

Comment: That's not the only way, but it's the simplest and cleanest, IMO. It _might_ be _slightly_ more efficient to set it on the `ListView`, but it wouldn't even by measurable, I'd bet. Even the system-provided item layouts - e.g., [`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) - use paddings.